# What does "social evolutionary outcome" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

[Han et. al.,2021](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0022109021000077) mentioned

> Our article differs from this literature in examining how social
> transmission biases such as SET affect the **social evolutionary outcome**

Simply speaking, SET is **Self-enhancing transmission bias**, which is the investor only report the good trading result but the bad results.

I am wondering what does "**social evolutionary outcome**" mean

[Social evolutionary](https://www.nature.com/subjects/social-evolution#:%7E:text=Definition,intuitive%20advantages%20of%20being%20selfish.) means:

"Social evolution is the area of evolutionary biology that studies **how social interactions, especially between individuals of the same species, arise, change and are maintained**. A particular focus is on how cooperative behavior can be beneficial despite the intuitive advantages of being selfish."

But what is the "outcome" in this phrase while "how cooperative behavior can be beneficial" already means outcome?

Comment: There is a lot of specific, technical language here. I think the question could be moved to a stack exchange where more people can discuss social evolution.

Comment: @AnonFNV could you please move it for me or give me the link of SE that I can post this question then?